# TbbcMoneyBundle ratio_provider: does not work now

Tags: symfony, money-php

I'm working with:

https://github.com/TheBigBrainsCompany/TbbcMoneyBundle

When I launch it with:

```
bin/console tbbc:money:ratio-fetch
```

I see an error in *Crawler.php line 565*:

```
The current node list is empty.

tbbc_money:
    currencies: ["UAH", "USD", "EUR", "PLN"]
    reference_currency: "USD"
    decimals: 2
    storage: doctrine
    #ratio_provider: tbbc_money.ratio_provider.yahoo_finance
    ratio_provider: tbbc_money.ratio_provider.google
```

Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

need to be replaced in the file \vendor\tbbc\money-bundle\Tbbc\MoneyBundle\Pair\RatioProvider\GoogleRatioProvider.php

```
protected function getEndpoint($units, Currency $referenceCurrency, Currency $currency)
{
    //https://finance.google.com/finance/converter
    return sprintf(
        'https://finance.google.com/bctzjpnsun/converter?a=%s&from=%s&to=%s',
        $units,
        $referenceCurrency->getCode(),
        $currency->getCode()
    );
}
```